# Apache returns empty response and must restart

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd

I have the classical LAMP configuration on several servers, on one server I can frequently see Apache returned an empty error.

I have PHP-FPM running to serve .php file, static pages like .html is okay however if I keep the server running for 1 day, .php will be inaccessible and returned empty response, I must restart httpd to recover this issue.

I can see the only error log in Apache is:

`[:error] [pid 21153] ModSecurity: ModSecurity requires mod_unique_id to be installed.`

However I have same configuration on other servers, both got this error but did not have this issue.

How should I diagnose this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Do you have the following line commented out in your config perhaps?

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

You may need to recompile Apache if you did not compile it with the --enable-unique-id flag (most distributions have it included in compiled version though possibly commented about in config as per above).

Answer (score -1):

If the apache is failing to respond after one or two days means it is a performance issue, consider increasing the worker process and servver process instances. Some basic example below, tweak it as per your needs to resolve the issue.

ServerLimit         16
StartServers         2
MaxRequestWorkers  150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25